# How do I get the sum of years from date column in reference to each ticker?(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that looks like that one below:

```
        Date    Open    High    Low    Close        Symbol
    1990-11-05  3.88    4.25    3.25    4.25        WIKI/DDD
    1990-11-06  3.50    4.25    3.50    3.62        WIKI/DDD
    1991-11-07  3.50    4.00    3.50    4.00        WIKI/DDD
    1990-11-08  4.00    4.00    3.75    4.00        WIKI/DDD
    2017-11-09  4.00    4.00    3.50    3.50        WIKI/DDD
    1990-11-05  3.88    4.25    3.25    4.25        WIKI/AAPL
    1990-11-06  3.50    4.25    3.50    3.62        WIKI/AAPL
    1995-11-07  3.50    4.00    3.50    4.00        WIKI/AAPL
    1995-11-08  4.00    4.00    3.75    4.00        WIKI/AAPL
    2017-11-09  4.00    4.00    3.50    3.50        WIKI/AAPL
```

What I am trying to is to build a new column that would sum and give me the number of years each company has been trading for.

```
        Date    Open    High    Low    Close        Symbol    Yrs_Publ_Trd
    1990-11-05  3.88    4.25    3.25    4.25        WIKI/DDD     34
    1990-11-06  3.50    4.25    3.50    3.62        WIKI/DDD     34
    1991-11-07  3.50    4.00    3.50    4.00        WIKI/DDD     34
    1990-11-08  4.00    4.00    3.75    4.00        WIKI/DDD     34
    2017-11-09  4.00    4.00    3.50    3.50        WIKI/DDD     34
    1990-11-05  3.88    4.25    3.25    4.25        WIKI/AAPL    28
    1990-11-06  3.50    4.25    3.50    3.62        WIKI/AAPL    28
    1995-11-07  3.50    4.00    3.50    4.00        WIKI/AAPL    28
    1995-11-08  4.00    4.00    3.75    4.00        WIKI/AAPL    28
    2017-11-09  4.00    4.00    3.50    3.50        WIKI/AAPL    28
```

my date column is a (datetime64[ns])

I tried using:

```
for i in mydata.groupby('Symbol').Date.size():
     print(mydata.Date.dt.year.max() -mydata.Date.dt.year.min())
```

And this:

```
for i in np.unique(mydata.Symbol):
    print(mydata.Date.dt.year.max() -mydata.Date.dt.year.min())
```

Comment: How can the answer be 34 for any of these records?

Comment: The year values were just for examples

Comment: Are you calculating the date from today (2018) or necessarily from the max value in the data?

Comment: from the max value in the data, thank you for the input, jezrael line of code got me the needed value. thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column:

```
mydata['Yrs_Publ_Trd'] = (mydata.groupby('Symbol').Date
                                .transform(lambda x: x.dt.year.max() - x.dt.year.min()))
```

Another solution:

```
g = mydata['Date'].dt.year.groupby(mydata['Symbol'])
mydata['Yrs_Publ_Trd'] = g.transform('max') - g.transform('min')
```

---

```
print (mydata)

        Date  Open  High   Low  Close     Symbol  Yrs_Publ_Trd
0 1990-11-05  3.88  4.25  3.25   4.25   WIKI/DDD            27
1 1990-11-06  3.50  4.25  3.50   3.62   WIKI/DDD            27
2 1991-11-07  3.50  4.00  3.50   4.00   WIKI/DDD            27
3 1990-11-08  4.00  4.00  3.75   4.00   WIKI/DDD            27
4 2017-11-09  4.00  4.00  3.50   3.50   WIKI/DDD            27
5 1990-11-05  3.88  4.25  3.25   4.25  WIKI/AAPL            27
6 1990-11-06  3.50  4.25  3.50   3.62  WIKI/AAPL            27
7 1995-11-07  3.50  4.00  3.50   4.00  WIKI/AAPL            27
8 1995-11-08  4.00  4.00  3.75   4.00  WIKI/AAPL            27
9 2017-11-09  4.00  4.00  3.50   3.50  WIKI/AAPL            27
```